# Python add to existing variable in except

Tags: python, python-requests

Quick example of code:

```
import requests
import re

for pages in range(1,10):

    post = 0

    myfile = open('posts.txt')
    data=myfile.read().splitlines()
    poster=data[post]

    postersend = {'param1': poster}

    try:

        resp = requests.get('http://www.postexample.com/pages={}'.format(pages), params=postersend).text

    except:
        //change post from 0 to 1 using + 1
        // tried post = post + 1 ( didn't work )
        continue
```

so what I'm trying to do is if

```
except:
```

is triggered then change

```
post = 0
```

to

```
post = 1
```

by adding + 1 each time we receive a exception

Comment: Well it won't because you immediately set `post = 0` on the next iteration of the `for` loop. Define `post = 0` before the `for` loop. Side note: I find "post" a really confusing name to keep track of errors for GET requests.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48410881) you, or just someone doing the same assignment?

Comment: omg thank you! @roganjosh

Comment: `// tried post = post + 1 ( didn't work )` What does "didn't work" mean? What happened when you tried this? What did you want to happen instead?

Comment: @blogbeard nope their code is slightly different to mine, in fact very different :)

Comment: @code-apprentice if you read the whole thread, you would clearly see what I wanted to happen lol.

Answer (score 1):

in your code you keep setting posts equal to 0 in your loop. Move the post = 0 part to *before* the loop and what you tried before should work.